# connect to a virtual machine remotely

Tags: virtualbox, network-bridge

I create a server in my virtual machine in ubuntu. But I can connect to it only from my machine. I can not connect to my virtual machine from outside computer which was in same LAN. When I search about this problem I found that using a network bridge this problem can be solved. I refer the following article. http://www.havetheknowhow.com/Configure-the-server/Network-Bridge.html 
But still I could not solve the problem.

Comment: Charith, Does your virutal machine has a public ip? What is your guest operating system. This question should be explained little bit more i think.

Comment: try running ifconfig or ipconfig in virtual machine and get the ip. May be that IP is not part of your LAN

Comment: Thank you dedunumax for responding . I run ifconfig and found the ip. but I only can connect to that using my machine. can not connect to it from any other machine.

Answer (score 0):

You need not to create a bridge to do that because VirtualBox does it for you.

Go to the VM settings network tab and make sure the first network adapter has the `bridge` option. That's enough to create the connectivity.

More of it, you can enable the remote desktop access (tab Display), if you want to connect the VM with RDP.

Make sure the VM has a valid IP address (it seems to be true yet), different from your host IP address. (And disable the bridge you created).